# What versions of AngularJS are compatible with UI-Bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

The plunker provided on the ui-bootstrap site used Angular 1.0.5 and ui-bootstrap 0.5.0 and works fine

http://plnkr.co/edit/zr30iUZHpP7RD7MUx47z

I only have ui-bootstrap version 0.4.0 available to me, and using the same plunker with the older verison makes things not work.

http://plnkr.co/edit/H7jC3T9gkfnCrkCSggdc

I've walked through different version of angular and none seem to work. So is there a compatibility list for the libraries somewhere?